# Certificate that person is living with a dead man, is there any analogue in US?

Tags: united-states, death, russia

There is a certificate in the Russian bureaucratic system that is literally called:

> Certificate that a person is currently living with a dead man

The reason for that is that a dead man is still registered in that place (referring to Russian [resident registration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resident_registration_in_Russia)). So it  really looks like a dead man is living with those who are alive "according to documents".

Is there any analogue in US? Or is the bureaucratic system built so that  you do not need to certify you are living with the dead?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a bureaucratic process, not the law itself.

Comment: @Nij , burocratic process is defined and ruled by law. E.g. according to the law of Russian Federation I have to have resident registration

Comment: In the US dead men are only allowed to vote, not live anywhere.  (Women too of course.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have never heard of anything like this.

I guess when you say "registered in that place" you are referring to Russian [resident registration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resident_registration_in_Russia).  The US doesn't have such a system, so this sort of certificate wouldn't even make sense.

Comment: You are right, "Resident Registration". So burocratic system does not need to know where you could be found in case e.g. debt collection (taxes), conscription? Sounds strange. How could be "Resident Registration" ommited in these cases?

Comment: Just a different system.  The state and federal governments know most people's addresses from things like drivers licenses, voter registration, and tax filing, but there isn't a single master registry.  Conscription ("selective service") is a separate registry also, which is only applicable to males age 18 to 25. One doesn't generally have to "unregister" from any of these things if you move or die, though there is a requirement to report deaths, so the state can correlate these databases if it wants to.

Comment: @IvanGerasimenko - for debt collection - if private it's their responsibility to find you.  If public (i.e., government) - they typically use your "last known address" and consider that good enough.  It can actually get people into trouble: if they're looking for you to see if you're the parent of a child who needs to pay child support, and you've moved, and you never get their letter - you could be on the hook for $$$$ anyway!  None of these systems are perfect, and when you consider they're _bureaucratic_ systems:  They're _much_ less perfect everywhere than you'd like.